# Installing cudamat and error for Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools

Tags: c++, anaconda, gpu, cudamat

I am trying to install cudamat but I always get the following error:

> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft
>   Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads

This is although I have installed Microsoft Visual Studio along with C++ tools. I am running the following command in the Anaconda command prompt: python `setup.py` install

I have also installed VS Code in Anaconda. However I still get the same error when trying to install cudamat.

I am running Windows 10

Thanks.

Comment: You should probably run this command from visual studio command prompt which set ups environment.

Comment: @VTT is probably correct; [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs) tells you how to launch it

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input @VTT and Neil. However, although I installed the python package for VS, when I typed python setup.py install, I got the following error:
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.